# Know about pinging

Tags: logging, ping

How can I get know that somebody was pinging my computer in various operating systems (Linux, Windows).

Are there some system logs recording such event?

Comment: What's your *real* question? Why do you give a damn about who is pinging your computer?

Comment: @Ben Pilbrow That's important to know if you want to have things under control. Somebody can discover your network infrastructure and use ping or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of the box most Linux distros and Windows don't have system logs that record such events.  You would need to install some network monitoring software.  On Windows you could install "Microsoft Network Monitor" and then filter on the ICMP protocol to see incoming PING packets

Answer (score 3):

Basically you just need a firewall setup to log denials then simply block ICMP - then just sit back and watch your logs.